single hyperlink for compressed citation ranges in natbib
Need to modify the hyperlink for natbib citation, when the reference citation is compressed, the clickable hyperlink should be the single link not separate link for compressed ranges ie., for example the ref. [1-4], the hyper link should be single clickable and the link should be for "1-4" and the target link should go for the Ref. 1 only.
How to modify in natbib.sty
MWE:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}

\cite{1}, \cite{2}, \cite{1,3,5}   \quad\cite{1,5,3}  \cite{1,2,3,4}


\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{1} bibliography 1
\bibitem{2} bibliography 2
\bibitem{3} bibliography 3
\bibitem{4} bibliography 4
\bibitem{5} bibliography 5

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

